# Liferay SOAP Services special character

Tags: web-services, soap, liferay, axis

I'm using Liferay SOAP Services for my Document Library.
When I tried to upload a file which name contains special characters for SOAP (like ':'), I'm getting an error like

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.rmi.RemoteException: Screenshot from 2015-02-10 14:43:33.png
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:rcop.agem.com.tr
java.rmi.RemoteException: Screenshot from 2015-02-10 14:43:33.png
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1789)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2965)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the problem is about colomn ":" character for SOAP... using a SOAP client it should escape strings for you.

But, are you sure the problem isn't that the colomn character is not allowed in some filesystems?

Comment: I'm using a linux system(Mint), likewise our liferay portal is running on tomcat which is inside a linux system (CentOS).I am uploading a file from my computer to liferay.So i don't think it is about filesystem.

Comment: I'm saying that it may be a limitation of filesystem or Jackrabbit (or any other repository you are using) or LR document library or LR service implementation... programmatically made to guarantee system portability. On my Unix machine I had a file with ":" in its name, and Alfresco (installed on a Linux machine) don't like the filename. By the way, if you are sure that it isn't the problem, are you sure filename values are escaped? Did you make an attempt with other "soap special characters", eg a file named my"test.png  (for starting to diagnose the problem)?

Comment: Yes, you are right,Liferay does not allow to upload files containing special characters in filename.Thanks for your interest.